# Angular 7 - Typescript syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I just need to understand the syntax below. I am using `angular-archwizard` libray for my wizard in my html page.

The **HTML**

```
<aw-wizard #wizard>
  <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Steptitle 1'" [canExit]="canExitStep1">
    <div class="centered-content">
      <div>
        Content: Step 1
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Allow exiting step 1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" awNextStep>Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aw-wizard-step>
</aw-wizard>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MovingDirection} from 'angular-archwizard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-can-exit-event',
  templateUrl: './can-exit-event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./can-exit-event.component.css']
})
export class CanExitEventComponent implements OnInit {

  public canExitStep1: (MovingDirection) => boolean = (direction) => {
    switch (direction) {
      case MovingDirection.Forwards:
        return true;
      case MovingDirection.Backwards:
        return false;
      case MovingDirection.Stay:
        return true;
    }
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

My point of interest is: `[canExit]="canExitStep1"` and the `public canExitStep1: (MovingDirection)` in the TypeScript part.

In the typescript part, is that a function and how is the `MovingDirection` passed? Basically I just need to understand the whole syntax from the `html` part to the `typescript` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[canExit]` can either be a `boolean` or a `function`. The function accepts a `MovingDirection`  enum and returns `Promise<boolean>` or `boolean`. This function holds any additional check or validation you need to perform to decide, if the step can be exited (both to the next step and to the previous step). If you don't have any logic to perform during the step change just pass in a `boolean` as the value of `[CanExit]`.

To make it easier to understand you could split the function declaration and function definition like so.

Declaration:

```
public canExitStep1: (MovingDirection) => boolean;
```

Definition:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.canExitStep1 = (direction) => {
      switch (direction) {
        case MovingDirection.Forwards:
          return true;
        case MovingDirection.Backwards:
          return false;
        case MovingDirection.Stay:
          return true;
      }
    };
 }
```

You can read more about the `[CanExit]` function here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-archwizard#canexit

I'll be happy to clarify any doubts you still may have.

Comment: I had read the documentation, it's just that I was unable to write a function for `[canExit]` so I stumbled upon an example in their `Github` which is the one above. So does this part `public canExitStep1: (MovingDirection) => boolean = (direction) =>` mean it's a function accepting a `MovingDirection` and returns a `boolean`? If that's the case then the syntax is a little bit strange for me :-)

Comment: Maybe if you split the declaration and definition it might be easier to understand the `canExit` method. I've updated the answer like so. Let me know if it clicks now.

Comment: Hmmmm, that makes sense. Thank you.